# C++ return null struct from function

Tags: c++, struct

I have a struct like this

```
struct AUTO{
   int weight;
   string name;
}
```

and I have a function that return a struct by passing `name`

```
AUTO autoByName(String name, AUTO a[], int ll)
{
   for(int i = 0; i < ll; i++)
   {
      if (name == a[i].name)
      {
         return a[i];
      }
   }

   // AND HERE ?????
}
```

but I don't know what return at the end of the function. Is there a `null` for struct ?

Comment: No. You would have to engineer some value that represents a null `AUTO`, or return some kind of optional object that can be tested (see `boost::optional` for example.)

Comment: @juanchopanza: You should post that as an answer.

Comment: There are many options: return a pointer (and nullptr is a valid return), throw an exception, return a bool and return the value via a reference parameter, have a "sentinel" value indicating a non-valid `AUTO`...

Comment: @KeithThompson I am looking for good duplicates. There are plenty out there, but so far I have only found ones with poor answers.

Comment: It makes no sense for a struct instance to be null.  This isn't Java where most everything is a reference to an object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a lot of options:

1. Give `AUTO` a way to represent a "no-value". For example by making weight -1. Or by adding a flag to it. This is pretty ugly; I don't recommend it, even though it's somewhat common in practice.
2. Return a (smart) pointer instead of value. This way you can return a `nullptr` in the case of error / no value. This is also ugly because it forces you to deal with pointers for not a very good reason.
3. Return a separate value to indicate success. For example adding a `bool &wasFound` argument to the function.
4. Return `boost::optional` or `std::pair<AUTO, bool>` to accomplish pretty much the same thing, but all wrapped up in the return value. This is probably the cleanest. This is how `std::map::find` works, for example.
5. Throw an exception. It's possible that this is acceptable if callers don't try to find items that don't exist. In other words, if "not found" is just a return value then don't throw an exception. If "not found" is truly a program error condition, throwing an exception may actually make sense. If you're not sure, don't throw an exception.

I'd recommend #4, or in rarer cases #5.

Comment: To be more explicit choose option #5 if not finding a matching object is an error case. If normally the object might not exist and you need a way to query its existence then choose option #4.